# Is there a way integrate each entry of a matrix and return the solutions as another matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, numerical-integration

I want to integrate a 3x3 matrix and have it return the solution as a 3x3 matrix, but I'm not sure if this is possible in python. Is there a command I can use? If not, should I set up some kind of for loop (could use some help with this as well if this is the case)?

I have tried using other suggestions, such as vectorize(integrate.quad)(integrandtemp, 0, 10) and vectorize(quad)(integrandtemp, 0, 10) but I get the same error I have been getting: "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars".

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate


def integrandtemp(s):
    K = 17.5
    r = 0.7
    x0 = 0.1

    dxdK = (x0 * x0 - x0 * x0 * np.exp(-r * s)) / (
        (x0 + K * np.exp(-r * s) - x0 * np.exp(-r * s)) ** 2
    )
    dxdr = (K * K * x0 * s * np.exp(-r * s) - K * x0 * x0 * s * np.exp(-r * s)) / (
        (x0 + K * np.exp(-r * s) - x0 * np.exp(-r * s)) ** 2
    )
    dxdx0 = (
        K * x0
        + K * K * np.exp(-r * s)
        - K * x0 * np.exp(-r * s)
        - K * x0
        + K * x0 * np.exp(-r * s)
    ) / ((x0 + K * np.exp(-r * s) - x0 * np.exp(-r * s)) ** 2)

    M = [dxdK, dxdr, dxdx0]
    M = np.array([M])

    transpose = M.T
    var = 0.16
    return (1 / var) * transpose @ M


F = np.vectorize(integrate.quad)(integrandtemp, 0, 10)
F_inv = np.inv(F)
```

I am getting this as the error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-a2757b67abc5> in <module>
     34     return (1/var)*transpose@M
     35 
---> 36 F = vectorize(integrate.quad)(integrandtemp, 0, 10)
     37 F_inv = inv(F)
     38 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1970             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   1971 
-> 1972         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   1973 
   1974     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2040             res = func()
   2041         else:
-> 2042             ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
   2043 
   2044             # Convert args to object arrays first

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   2000 
   2001             inputs = [arg.flat[0] for arg in args]
-> 2002             outputs = func(*inputs)
   2003 
   2004             # Performance note: profiling indicates that -- for simple

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    339     if weight is None:
    340         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 341                        points)
    342     else:
    343         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    446     if points is None:
    447         if infbounds == 0:
--> 448             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    449         else:
    450             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I need it to return another 3x3 matrix so that I can take the inverse and use it in what I am actually trying to solve.

Comment: which lines give error ? You can always use more `print()` to see values in all variables. You can also split calculation to smaller parts and print these parts to check if they are correct.

Comment: I will edit that in, but it's a long error message

Comment: I have printed M, transpose, and their product to make sure these are not the issue. It's F = vectorize(integrate.quad)(integrandtemp, 0, 10) that is giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

[quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine) does quadrature for array-valued functions:

```py
import numpy as np
import quadpy


def integrandtemp(S):
    out = []
    for s in S:
        K = 17.5
        r = 0.7
        x0 = 0.1

        dxdK = (x0 * x0 - x0 * x0 * np.exp(-r * s)) / (
            (x0 + K * np.exp(-r * s) - x0 * np.exp(-r * s)) ** 2
        )
        dxdr = (K * K * x0 * s * np.exp(-r * s) - K * x0 * x0 * s * np.exp(-r * s)) / (
            (x0 + K * np.exp(-r * s) - x0 * np.exp(-r * s)) ** 2
        )
        dxdx0 = (
            K * x0
            + K * K * np.exp(-r * s)
            - K * x0 * np.exp(-r * s)
            - K * x0
            + K * x0 * np.exp(-r * s)
        ) / ((x0 + K * np.exp(-r * s) - x0 * np.exp(-r * s)) ** 2)

        M = [dxdK, dxdr, dxdx0]
        M = np.array([M])

        transpose = M.T
        var = 0.16

        out.append((1 / var) * transpose @ M)

    out = np.array(out)
    out = np.moveaxis(out, 0, -1)
    return out


scheme = quadpy.line_segment.gauss_legendre(10)
val = scheme.integrate(integrandtemp, [0, 10])
print(val)
```

```
[[4.78541989e+00 2.77802115e+02 3.35326738e+02]
 [2.77802115e+02 2.32166322e+04 3.12478945e+04]
 [3.35326738e+02 3.12478945e+04 4.37373431e+04]]
```

Instead of looping over `S`, you can also vectorize your function for speed. Note that the output has to have the shape `(3, 3, input_shape)`.